# How can I add space in PHP between two outputs

Tags: php, html, spacing

I am new to php and trying to do this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo 'Welcome'.$_GET['name'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php code which displays my name entered by using a html form. When submit button is pressed I get this output :- WelcomeNick Watterson

But I am trying to add space between Welcome and Nick. How can I do this in this code?

Comment: just put space `echo 'Welcome '.$_GET['name'];`

Comment: Thanks bro! It worked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use the below code

```
<?php
echo 'Welcome&nbsp;'.$_GET['name'];
?>
```

is the html entity code for creating an single space character.

You can also use the below code:

```
<?php
    echo 'Welcome '.$_GET['name'];
 ?>
```

Will also work because one empty space is interpreted by the browsers directly.

Comment: Yes you are right. Both are working in the same manner. Thanks!

Comment: Just a word of advise, never output any input from a form directly to the screen, as it poses a security risk, filter it before echoing to screen, in you case use filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)

Comment: Actually I am new to php. Will follow these instructions also. Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$strings = array('Hello', 'World!');
// Usual concatenation
echo $strings[0] . ' ' . $strings[1];
// Some implode
echo implode(' ', $strings);
```